# Making sure jsavascript files are not cached

Tags: javascript, caching

We're pushing out updates pretty regulalry and want to make sure our vistors are not pulling cached external javascript files. Seen a lot of complex solutions to this problem. Was wondering if there were any drawbacks to using the old school method of appending a timestamp to the src:

```
<script>
date = new Date();
document.write('<scr' + 'ipt type="text/javascript" src="/js.js?' + date.getTime() + '"></scr' + 'ipt>')
</script>
```

The simple things often work best.

Answer (score 0):

It's not a good idea, because this way you disable cache totally. So users will download your scripts with each page reload. It will increase your the load time of your site and decrease it's usability.

Better way is to save timestamp everytime you update your script and add this timestamp to script src.

```
<script src="/js?timestamp_of_last_script_version"></script>
```

Comment: That's exactly what we want. We have regulalry updated data in this JS file, which weighs less than 1 KB.